# In .htaccess remove .php extension only from one particular file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Have file `create.php`

Want if user types `domain.com/create.php` show `domain.com/create`

in .htaccess above `RewriteEngine on` placed this

```
RewriteRule ^create/?$ create.php [NC]
```

But if i type `domain.com/create.php`, i see `.php`

how to allow access to `create.php` file only from url `domain.com/create`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect create.php to create
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(create)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally forward create to create.php
RewriteRule ^(create)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava. I still don't understant why it's a redirect loop, if the first use external 301. And why that works if you test before in %{THE_REQUEST}

Comment: Without `%{THE_REQUEST}` it will cause redirect loop because `REQUEST_URI` changes between `create` and `create.php` due to both rules. However `%{THE_REQUEST}` doesn't change with application of other rules and hence stops looping.

Comment: I really think it was that the loop. But because the first is with [L] and [R=301], I thought she was extern and therefore never reached the second test, except in a second and final browser request.

Comment: I see the loop. But I thought [R=302,L] and [L] alone should prevent this problem. Thanks again !

Comment: On server works, but on local computer with wamp does not work. OK, seems something wrong with my local computer (create.php is not in root).

Comment: Yes this rule will work when `create.php` is in `DocumentRoot`. Otherwise `RewriteBase` and `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(create)\.php[\s?] [NC]` lines need to be changed.

Comment: If `create.php` is in `subfolder`, then changed to `RewriteBase /subfolder/` and `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(subfolder/create)\.php[\s?] [NC]` Yes, seems works. Just question regarding `R=302`. I changed to `R=301` and it works. I "moved" `create.php` to `create` permanently (not temporary)

Comment: i have same problem but now working thanks  anubhava